# Android Studio build configurations

Tags: android, configuration, android-studio

I'm wondering how to create different build configurations, having different constants for debug and release builds using Android Studio (things like, server addresses, API keys,…).

Comment: This really doesn't look like a duplicate of the indicated question.

Answer (score 6):

Edit the `build.gradle` file in your module and add any of the following to your `android{}` container.

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("path relative to the root of the project")
            storePassword "PASSWORD!"
            keyAlias "projectname"
            keyPassword "PASSWORD!"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debugRelease.initWith(buildTypes.release)
        debugRelease {
            debuggable true
            packageNameSuffix '.debugrelease'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}
```

This adds 3 build types (release, debugRelease and debug)

both release and debugRelease use the same keys and debugRelease is a copy of Release.

Comment: It was not exactly what I was looking for, but it was enough to point me in the right direction.